# PWA with unsecure websocket to local application

Tags: typescript, websocket, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr, asp.net-core-3.0

I am struggling to get my head around HTTP, HTTPS, WS, and WSS.

I have a vue PWA that is hosted on a HTTPS endpoint.
Inside that app I try to connect to a local PC which hosts a SignalR-hub on a HTTP endpoint.

I am using the `@aspnetcore/signalr` typescript package. It's all working fine on the development machine but as soon as I try it with the PWA I get the following error:

`Error: Failed to start the connection: SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.`

My connectionbuilder looks like this:

```js
this.signalRConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(`http://${this.localIp}/${this.hubName}`, {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
      })
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();
```

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible?

Comment: I guess the issue is _"hosted on a **HTTPS** endpoint. Inside that app I try to connect to a local PC which hosts a SignalR-hub on a **HTTP** endpoint."_ Try make the local PC run "HTTPS".

Comment: That's indeed the path I went with.  Both are now running on HTTPS. Thanks for the suggestion though. @LGSon

Answer (score 0):

Just like the error mentioned insecure websocket connection from site with HTTPS. Ensure WSS protocol is supported for the websocket server you are connecting to it should be wss://

Comment: Changing the `.withUrl(`http://${this.localIp}/${this.hubName}` line with `wss://` doesn't do the trick. I get `WebSocket connection to 'wss://{ip}/{hubname}' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`. Or does it require backend changes aswell?

Comment: i just looked up HubConnectionBuilder class. That's for HTTP/S connection.So the original value you have put may be correct. I am not sure where in your code you are setting the address for the websocket server

Comment: Does it really matter where I set the address? Even hardcoded ip/hubname gives the same result. Or what are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to solve a similar problem. I ended up with the following solution. I created a new A record for my local websocket server, something like ws.example.org with an IP address of the server in my local network. Then I had to add a SSL certificate for this server. For this I used certbot to create a manual certificate (my server is not connected to the internet so an automatic challenge is not possible, can be scripted though). Finally after installing the certificate my PWA was able to make the wss connection.